# How to pass onClick event from parent to children?

Tags: android

I have a *Cardview* that contains as child a *RelativeLayout* as the header of the card.

When I'm on a tablet the whole card should be clickable, and when I'm on a phone only the header should be clickable.

The problem that I have is when I'm on the tablet the header is not seeing the onClick event of it's parent. Did I do something wrong?

```
if (isTablet(getContext())) {
        cardView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            //here the cardHeader doesn't have the clickevent of it's parent
            // do something
        });
} else if (isPhone(getContext())) {
        cardHeader.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            // do something
 });
```

And the xml file:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            ....contains other views

          </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: do share your xml file

Comment: Your question is little bit confusing. What you want to achieve? header click on phone and card click on tablet? Am I right?

Comment: yes. that's right. the problem I have is when on tablet the header is not clickable.

Comment: What you want exactly then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your click for child `View` and when needed add also `OnClickListener` for parent, and inside call `cardHeader.performClick()` or `cardHeader.callOnClick()` method

```
cardHeader.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        // do something
});

if (isTablet(getContext())) {
    cardView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        cardHeader.callOnClick();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it Header is not clickable in the case of tablet. But I guess your requirement is, You want header to be clickable in both cases whether its tablet or phone and card should be clickable only in case of Tablet.

```
cardHeader.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        // do something
});

if (isTablet(getContext())) {
    cardView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        //do something
    });
}
```